# Creating an object from class A...Z (scalable) depending on the value of a string

Tags: java, reflection

Is this possible? Could I instance an object from one class or another depending on the value of a string?

I have a code like this:

```
public Map<Language, IConverter> converters;

// ...

public IConverter buildConverter(Language lang) {
    IConverter converter = new ???(buildMap(lang)); <---- Problem here

    converters.put(lang, converter);
}

public Map<Integer, String> buildMap(Language lang) {
    // ...
}
```

Where `Language` is a bean class containing a string which identifies a language and `IConverter` is an interface implemented by several (undefined amount) concrete `Converter`.

Do I need to add an `if` clause per supported `Converter`? Is there anyway to idenfity which string belongs to which class, maybe with a Map or something like that?

I may drop the Language class, because it is kind of shallow and can't see it scalating.

**EDIT**

I ended using Jesper's answer, I had to adapt my `Language` class for it to contain the full language name, and concatenating the package name, the languagename and "Converter".

Boy, is Reflection scary at first, so many, many Exceptions.

Comment: [Example of GoF Desing Patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/1654265): take a look at ***Creational patterns***.

Comment: can you give us sample code of if statement so us to understand it better? thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the name of the class in a string, you can create a new instance of it using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). For example:

```
String className = "com.mycompany.SomeConverter";

// Creates an instance of the class by using the no-args constructor
IConverter converter = (IConverter) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

If you want to use a specific constructor with arguments:

```
// For example, look for a constructor that takes one argument, a String
Constructor constr = Class.forName(className).getConstructor(String.class);

// Create a new instance, passing "Hello" as the argument
IConverter converter = (IConverter) constr.newInstance("Hello");
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this. Sadly, I had to restructure huge parts of my little project. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need something very similar to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you mean this

```
Constructor constr = Class.forName("com.yourpackage.converter" + lang.getYourString()).getConstructor(buildMap_function_returned_class.class);

IConverter converter = (IConverter) constr.newInstance(buildMap(lang));
```